# link progress bar with value in function during function execution

Tags: c#, wpf

I've Created a class with public function returns a list during execution public int increasing to 100 at the end of function this value for progress bar  is increasing during function
how to make synchronization between public int in the class and the progress bar in the wpf form
at the end I want the sList as result and WeekListsProgress as progressbar vlaue

```
public class SchedHandler
    {
        public static List<Subject4Sched> SubSchedList = GetSchedSubList();
        public static int WeekSum = SubSchedList.Sum(x => x.WeekCount);
        public static int AssignSum = SubSchedList.Sum(x => x.Assigned);
        public static SchoolEntitiesProFinal ProDb;
        public static int WeekListsProgress = 0;
        public static List<SubWeekCount> GetSubList(int semId)
        {
            ProDb = new SchoolEntitiesProFinal();
            List<sp_GetSubWeekCountList_Result> subs = ProDb.sp_GetSubWeekCountList(semId).ToList();
            return subs.Select(item => new SubWeekCount(item.subid, item.subject, item.sessioncount)).ToList();
        }
        public List<SubWeekCount> SubList = GetSubList(1);

        //1- Insert Subjects With 0 Assigned
        public static void InsertSubjects(int subid,string subName, int week, int ass)
        {
            var sub = new tbl_schedule();
            sub.subid = subid;
            sub.subname = subName;
            sub.weekly = week;
            sub.assigned = ass;
           
            try
            {
                using (var db = new SchoolEntitiesProFinal())
                {
                    db.tbl_schedule.Add(sub);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        public static void UpdtaeSubjects(int subid)
        {
            tbl_schedule sub = ProDb.tbl_schedule.FirstOrDefault(x => x.subid == subid);
            

            try
            {
                if (sub != null) sub.assigned = sub.assigned + 1;
                ProDb.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error With Databse!!!");
            }
        }
        public static void RemoveSubjects(int subid)
        {
            tbl_schedule sub = ProDb.tbl_schedule.FirstOrDefault(x => x.subid == subid);
            try
            {
                if (sub!=null)
                {
                    if (sub.assigned == sub.weekly)
                    {
                        ProDb.tbl_schedule.Remove(sub);
                        ProDb.SaveChanges();
                    } 
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error With Databse!!!");
            }
        }
        public static void RemoveAllSubjects()
        {
            List<tbl_schedule> sub = ProDb.tbl_schedule.ToList();
            try
            {
                ProDb.tbl_schedule.RemoveRange(sub);
                ProDb.SaveChanges();
                
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error With Databse!!!");
            }
        }
        public static int GetSubAssigned(int subid)
        {
            ProDb = new SchoolEntitiesProFinal();

            var sub = ProDb.tbl_schedule.FirstOrDefault(x => x.subid == subid);
            int count = 0;

            if (sub != null) count = sub.assigned;

            return count;
        }
        public static List<Subject4Sched> GetSchedSubList()
        {
            ProDb = new SchoolEntitiesProFinal();
            var subs = ProDb.tbl_schedule.ToList();
            return subs.Select(item => new Subject4Sched(item.subid, item.subname, item.weekly, item.assigned)).ToList();
        }
        public static Subject4Sched GetSub()
        {
            ProDb = new SchoolEntitiesProFinal();
            var f = ProDb.tbl_schedule.First();
            var sub = new Subject4Sched(f.subid, f.subname,f.weekly,f.assigned);
            return sub;
        }
        public static List<Sessions> WeekLists(int semId)
        {
            WeekListsProgress = 0;

            var sat = new List<Subject4Sched>();
            var sun = new List<Subject4Sched>();
            var mon = new List<Subject4Sched>();
            var tues = new List<Subject4Sched>();
            var wed = new List<Subject4Sched>();
            var thur = new List<Subject4Sched>();
            var fri = new List<Subject4Sched>();

            string[] weekEnds = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Program Files\School Manager\Pars Text\WeekEnds.txt");
            var holidaylist = weekEnds.Select(line => line.Split(',')).Select(tokens => tokens[0]).ToList();

            // Get Subjects For Semester 
            var subList = GetSubList(semId);
            RemoveAllSubjects();
            int v = 0;
            foreach (var sub in subList)
            {
                InsertSubjects(sub.SubId, sub.SubName, sub.WeekCount, 0);
                v += (20/subList.Count);
            }

            WeekListsProgress = 20;
            int weekDaysCount = 7 - holidaylist.Count;
            int sessionsCount = subList.Sum(x => x.WeekCount);
            var sessionsPerDay = Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDouble(sessionsCount) / Convert.ToDouble(weekDaysCount));

            for (int x = 0; x < sessionsCount; x++)
            {
                foreach (var sched in SubSchedList.ToList())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < sched.WeekCount; i++)
                    {
                        if (i < sched.WeekCount)
                        {
                            if (sat.Count < sessionsPerDay && !holidaylist.Contains(DayOfWeek.Saturday.ToString()))
                            {
                                int subCount = sat.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId) +
                                               sun.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId) +
                                               mon.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId) +
                                               tues.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId) +
                                               wed.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId) +
                                               thur.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId) +
                                               fri.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId);
                                WeekListsProgress += 60 / sessionsCount;

                                if (subCount < sched.WeekCount)
                                {
                                    sat.Add(new Subject4Sched(sched.SubId, sched.SubName, sched.WeekCount, sched.Assigned++));
                                    UpdtaeSubjects(sched.SubId);
                                    i++;
                                    x++; 
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        if (i < sched.WeekCount)
                        {
                            if (sun.Count < sessionsPerDay && !holidaylist.Contains(DayOfWeek.Sunday.ToString()))
                            {
                                int subCount = sat.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId) +
                                               sun.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId) +
                                               mon.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId) +
                                               tues.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId) +
                                               wed.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId) +
                                               thur.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId) +
                                               fri.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId);
                                WeekListsProgress += 60 / sessionsCount;

                                if (subCount < sched.WeekCount)
                                {
                                    sun.Add(new Subject4Sched(sched.SubId, sched.SubName, sched.WeekCount,
                                        sched.Assigned++));
                                    UpdtaeSubjects(sched.SubId);
                                    i++;
                                    x++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        if (i < sched.WeekCount)
                        {
                            if (mon.Count < sessionsPerDay && !holidaylist.Contains(DayOfWeek.Monday.ToString()))
                            {
                                int subCount = sat.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId) +
                                               sun.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId) +
                                               mon.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId) +
                                               tues.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId) +
                                               wed.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId) +
                                               thur.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId) +
                                               fri.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId);
                                WeekListsProgress += 60 / sessionsCount;

                                if (subCount < sched.WeekCount)
                                {
                                    mon.Add(new Subject4Sched(sched.SubId, sched.SubName, sched.WeekCount,
                                        sched.Assigned++));
                                    UpdtaeSubjects(sched.SubId);
                                    i++;
                                    x++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        if (i < sched.WeekCount)
                        {
                            if (tues.Count < sessionsPerDay && !holidaylist.Contains(DayOfWeek.Tuesday.ToString()))
                            {
                                int subCount = sat.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId) +
                                               sun.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId) +
                                               mon.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId) +
                                               tues.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId) +
                                               wed.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId) +
                                               thur.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId) +
                                               fri.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId);
                                WeekListsProgress += 60 / sessionsCount;

                                if (subCount < sched.WeekCount)
                                {
                                    tues.Add(new Subject4Sched(sched.SubId, sched.SubName, sched.WeekCount,
                                        sched.Assigned++));
                                    UpdtaeSubjects(sched.SubId);
                                    i++;
                                    x++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        if (i < sched.WeekCount)
                        {
                            if (wed.Count < sessionsPerDay && !holidaylist.Contains(DayOfWeek.Wednesday.ToString()))
                            {
                                int subCount = sat.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId) +
                                               sun.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId) +
                                               mon.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId) +
                                               tues.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId) +
                                               wed.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId) +
                                               thur.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId) +
                                               fri.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId);
                                WeekListsProgress += 60 / sessionsCount;

                                if (subCount < sched.WeekCount)
                                {
                                    wed.Add(new Subject4Sched(sched.SubId, sched.SubName, sched.WeekCount,
                                        sched.Assigned++));
                                    UpdtaeSubjects(sched.SubId);
                                    i++;
                                    x++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        if (i < sched.WeekCount)
                        {
                            if (thur.Count < sessionsPerDay && !holidaylist.Contains(DayOfWeek.Thursday.ToString()))
                            {
                                int subCount = sat.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId) +
                                               sun.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId) +
                                               mon.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId) +
                                               tues.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId) +
                                               wed.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId) +
                                               thur.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId) +
                                               fri.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId);
                                WeekListsProgress += 60 / sessionsCount;

                                if (subCount < sched.WeekCount)
                                {
                                    thur.Add(new Subject4Sched(sched.SubId, sched.SubName, sched.WeekCount,
                                        sched.Assigned++));
                                    UpdtaeSubjects(sched.SubId);
                                    i++;
                                    x++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        if (i < sched.WeekCount)
                        {
                            if (fri.Count < sessionsPerDay && !holidaylist.Contains(DayOfWeek.Friday.ToString()))
                            {
                                int subCount = sat.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId) +
                                               sun.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId) +
                                               mon.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId) +
                                               tues.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId) +
                                               wed.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId) +
                                               thur.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId) +
                                               fri.Count(y => y.SubId == sched.SubId);
                                WeekListsProgress += 60 / sessionsCount;

                                if (subCount < sched.WeekCount)
                                {
                                    fri.Add(new Subject4Sched(sched.SubId, sched.SubName, sched.WeekCount,
                                        sched.Assigned++));
                                    UpdtaeSubjects(sched.SubId);
                                    i++;
                                    x++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            WeekListsProgress = 80;

            int[] counts = {sat.Count, sun.Count, mon.Count, tues.Count, wed.Count, thur.Count, fri.Count};
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            var sList=new List<Sessions>();
            for (int i = 0; i < counts.Max(); i++)
            {
                string s1="";string s2 = "";string s3 = "";string s4 = ""; string s5 = ""; string s6 = ""; string s7 = "";
                if (sat.Count>i)
                {
                    s1 = sat[i].SubName;
                }
                if (sun.Count > i)
                {
                    s2 = sun[i].SubName;
                }
                if (mon.Count > i)
                {
                    s3 = mon[i].SubName;
                }
                if (tues.Count > i)
                {
                    s4 = tues[i].SubName;
                }
                if (wed.Count > i)
                {
                    s5 = wed[i].SubName;
                }
                if (thur.Count > i)
                {
                    s6 = thur[i].SubName;
                }
                if (fri.Count > i)
                {
                    s7 = fri[i].SubName;
                }
                
                sList.Add(new Sessions(i,s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7));
                WeekListsProgress += 20/counts.Max();
            }
            WeekListsProgress = 100;
            return sList;
        }
       


    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but when you can set dot and semicolons in your code, why not in your question? It's almost unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend using a class property to report progress, especially not a static property. One reason is that it makes the method not threadsafe, but it can also make the class more difficult to use since it is not obvious what, if any methods update the progress.

My preferred way is to take a parameter in your method, and update the progress property of this parameter. Something like

```
public class ProgressDestination{
    public double Progress {get;set;} // in range 0,1
    public string Description {get;set;} // Optional text 
}
```

To connect this with the UI I prefer to use a poller

```
public class ProgressPoller : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ProgressDestination Progress { get; } = new ProgressDestination();
    private readonly DispatcherTimer timer;
    public ProgressPoller()
    {
        timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Tick += OnTick;
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.2);
    }

    private void OnTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Value = (int) (Progress.Progress * MaxValue);
        Description = Progress.Description;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Value));
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Description));
    }

    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int MaxValue { get; } = 100;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

So that the Progress Bar can simply bind to the value property of the poller.

```
 <ProgressBar 
            x:Name="progressBar"
            Minimum ="0" 
            Maximum="{Binding poller.MaxValue}" 
            Value="{Binding poller.Value, Mode=OneWay}">
```

This ensures that the progress bar is updated on the main thread, and it has a fixed update rate, regardless of how fast the background code updates the progress variable.

This is a simplification, it might for example need some way to reset or turn of the poller if no operation is in progress. Or a way to queue operations if multiple operations might run concurrently. It is also possible to extend this approach to allow multiple hierarchical progress reporting.

Comment: Thank you very much it was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can define an event in the `SchedHandler` class and send that event to the instance of the class where each instance of the class was created, with the changes applied to the control.

```
public class SchedHandler
{
   public delegate void ProgressChangeDelegate(double Persentage);
   public static event ProgressChangeDelegate OnProgressChanged;
   public SchedHandler()
   { 
      OnProgressChanged += delegate { };
   }

   public static List<Sessions> WeekLists(int semId)
   {
      ///.........
      WeekListsProgress += 60 / sessionsCount;
      OnProgressChanged(WeekListsProgress);
      ///.........
   }
   //..........................
   //..........................
}
```

*Of course, be sure to call OnProgressChanged wherever the Progressber value needs to be updated.*

**now use**

```
SchedHandler.OnProgressChanged += schedHandler_OnProgressChanged;

private void schedHandler_OnProgressChanged(double Persentage)
{
    Func<int> del = delegate()
    {
        progressbar1.Percentage = Persentage;
        return 0;
    };
    Dispatcher.Invoke(del);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much it was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQMNFEz5IVU&t=1s

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var sl = new List<Sessions>();
            var progress = new Progress<int>(value =>
            {
                pbWeekList.Value =value ;
            });
            await Task.Run(() => sl= SchedHandler.WeekLists(1, progress));
            dg.ItemsSource = sl;
        }
```

but first you must change to

```
public static List<Sessions> WeekLists(int semId,IProgress<int> progress)
    {
        WeekListsProgress = 0;
        progress.Report(WeekListsProgress);
         /////////////////////
           /////////////////
             ////////////////

        Thread.Sleep(100);
        WeekListsProgress = 100;
        progress.Report(WeekListsProgress);
        return sList;
    }
```